# What is the cause of the error "Package keyval Error: orientation undefined"

Tags: graphics, errors

When I try to compile the following code on Windows using MikTeX and TexWorks,

I get the error "Package keyval Error: orientation undefined".

I understand that it is referring to line 69, which has a `\end{frame}`.  What I do not know is why is this LaTeX code not compiling on Texworks on Windows XP? It works on Kile on an Ubuntu box.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{beamerthemebars}
% \usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz} % for pictures and text as overlay
\usepackage{pgfpages}
% \usepackage{collect}
% \setbeameroption{show notes on second}


\title{EEE C383 Communication Systems}

\author{Ananth Saradhi}



\AtBeginSection
{
    \begin{frame}{Review of Previous Class}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \date{\today}
       \frametitle{Where are We ?}
       \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection
        \date{\today}
        \author{Ananth Saradhi}
    \end{center}

    \end{frame}

}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=1.0\paperwidth,height = 1.0
\paperheight, orientation= landscape]{lecture_template.pdf}}


\includeonly{lecture - 3}

\begin{document}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} % adds pause after every ``item``

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]



\begin{frame}{Introduction}


\end{frame} % This is line 69.....


\begin{frame}{History of Electronic Communication}
 %insert timeline from timetoast.com


\end{frame}



\begin{frame}{Communication system}
 % Insert three block diagram of a comunication  system

 \begin{itemize}
  \item Information
  \item Source
  \item Channel
  \item Destination
 \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Errors:

---

```
lectures.tex
69
Package keyval Error: orientation undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.69 \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 3):

`orientation` is an undefined key for `\includegraphics`. Maybe you're interested in some form of rotation, which you can specify using the `angle` key-value.

Why did it compile on a different system? Perhaps it passed through the error due to switch `-interaction=nonstopmode`.